# InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34: Database (homestead) does not exist

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5

I am following the Series Laravel 5 from scratch in Laracasts and I am, in specific, on the lesson "Fetching Data".

I created the database.sqlite file, I added some data from the tinker and was able to retrieve them in the console. Then, I try to replicate what the video does.

My cards controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Http\Requests;

class CardsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $cards = \DB::table('cards')->get();
        return view('cards.index', compact('cards'));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to load the /cards route I have the following error

```
InvalidArgumentException in SQLiteConnector.php line 34:
Database (homestead) does not exist.
```

This is my `env` file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:P3ZgRMRkb2e8+x7S9rDLLB+bKJdR5Unpj8zXBUIHIZE=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_FILE=database.sqlite


CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under that line referenced in your error, is the following:

```
    // Here we'll verify that the SQLite database exists before going any further
    // as the developer probably wants to know if the database exists and this
    // SQLite driver will not throw any exception if it does not by default.
    if ($path === false) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Database (${config['database']}) does not exist.");
    }
```

Looking at the comment above the method, it seems that your path is not correctly set. I believe the correct environment variable should be:

`DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite`

instead of

`DB_FILE=database/database.sqlite`

If not, check your `config/database.php` file, and look for this section:

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')), // this line!
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed also (at least in Laravel version 5.2.29 on a mac) the path must be an absolute path. The weird thing is, for running migrations a relative path will work but the application then fails when trying to access the DB after that